# Mongoose schema keeps breaking: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `AnalyticsSchema` model once compiled

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

Schema keeps breaking op random times:

OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `AnalyticsSchema` model once compiled.
at Mongoose.model (C:\Users\Desktop\Workspace_Git_REPOS\secforhire\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:563:13)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./models/analytics.js:16:135)
at (rsc)/./models/analytics.js (C:\Users\Desktop\Workspace_Git_REPOS\secforhire.next\server\app\api\analytics\route.js:72:1)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\Desktop\Workspace_Git_REPOS\secforhire.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/analytics/route.js:7:75)

```
import mongoose, { Schema, models } from "mongoose";

const analyticsSchema = new Schema({
    namespace: String,
    event: Object,
    counter: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1 
    },
});

const AnalyticsModel = models.AnalyticsModel || mongoose.model("AnalyticsSchema", analyticsSchema);
export default AnalyticsModel;
```

I have used many combos but some how it keeps breaking random.

Tried to find a solution, redon the code multiple times, checked multiple sourses.

Comment: Made a mistake: 
```
const AnalyticsModel = models.AnalyticsModel || mongoose.model("AnalyticsModel", analyticsSchema);
export default AnalyticsModel;
```